# open URL with Java in background

Tags: java, url

have a problem here with Java. I'm a beginner and I don't know why it's not working.

What I want:
I have an homepage, I want to change some properties of a module. Therefore I have an .php-file. Going to the URL (looks like http://subdomain.domain.de/path_to_module/file.php?property=XY&api=Z) is all I have to do. To make this faster and easier especially also for friends, I want to code a little app.

I looked up google and get so far:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
               try {
                   URL url = new URL("http://subdomain.domain.de/path_to_module/file.php? 
    property=XY&api=Z");

                   HttpURLConnection connection = null ;
                   try {
                       connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                       if( connection != null )
                           connection.disconnect() ;
                   }
               } catch (MalformedURLException e){
               } catch (IOException e){}
            }
```

But that isn't working. The App don't crash or anything. It looks like it works, but when you look on the website it isn't changing anything.
Go to the URL by hand is working, so this can't be the problem...

Do you have any ideas, how to solve the problem?

Please excuse bad spelling or something like that, I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

The URL [`openConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection--) method doesn't make the connection:

> It should be noted that a URLConnection instance does not establish the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when calling URLConnection.connect().

You have to call [`URLConnection.connect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect--) on the `HttpURLConnection` object it returns.

> Opens a communications link to the resource referenced by this URL, if such a connection has not already been established.

The HttpURLConnection doesn't begin transferring data right away because you may want to set HTTP headers, or you may want to do a POST or a PUT instead of a GET. You may have to get the input stream, and possibly even read from it, to cause it to make a GET request from the server (if that is what you are trying to do).

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
is.transferTo(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
```

This will read all the data from the connection and write it to a buffer, which you could discard if you don't care about its contents.

Comment: Hey have some more question, too long for a comment, so I add a new answer. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @David Conrad thanks for your help.

If I get you right, the new Code should look like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
               try {
                   URL url = new URL("http://subdomain.domain.de/path_to_module/file.php? 
    property=XY&api=Z");

                   HttpURLConnection connection = null ;
                   try {
                       connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                       connection.connect();
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                       if( connection != null )
                           connection.disconnect() ;
                   }
               } catch (MalformedURLException e){
               } catch (IOException e){}
            }
```

I tried it, but it didn't work. Did I missunderstand what you are talking about?

Comment: This isn't the right way to use answers, but I've updated my answer with some additional specifics.